# Looking for an explanation for a const function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how this worked, and what each part meant.

```js
const factors = number => [...Array(number + 1).keys()].filter(i=>number % i === 0);
```

I have done some research on some of the bits but I don't really understand how it goes together as a whole. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is there any particular part you're not understanding?

Comment: @TorNato basically you will return factors of `number` (from 0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's break it down:

- `Array(number + 1)`: Creates an array with `number + 1` empty elements
- `Array(number + 1).keys()`: Retrieves the indices of the array in the form of an iterator
- `[...Array(number + 1).keys()]`: Creates an array from the iterator (contains elements `0, 1, 2, ..., (number - 1), number`)
- `.filter(cb)`: Calls the function `cb` for each value in the array, and returns a new array containing the values for which the callback (`cb`) has returned `true` (uses implicit boolean conversion)
- `i => number % i === 0`: Gets called for each value of the array, current element stored to `i`
- `number % i`: Divides `number` with `i` and returns the remainder
- `number % i === 0`: Checks if the remainder equal to zero (i.e. if `number` perfectly divisible by `i`)
- `.filter(i => number % i === 0)`: Filters the array, keeping the elements that are the divisors of `number`

So,

```
number => [...Array(number + 1).keys()].filter(i => number % i === 0);
```

creates a function, that returns an array with the divisors of the given `number`.

Answer (score 3):

Let's break it down...

1. `Array(number + 1)`

   This is the [array constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array), creating a sparse array with length `number + 1`
2. `.keys()`

   Using [`Array.prototype.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys) to get an iterator for the array keys which are *[0, number]*

   <sup>FYI, this is [interval notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)), not an array</sup>
3. `[...Array(number + 1).keys()]`

   Using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) on an iterator converts it to an array, so now we have something like

   ```js
   [0, 1, 2, ..., number]
   ```
4. `.filter(i=>number % i === 0)`

   Uses [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to reduce the ranged array above to one where the values divide evenly into `number`

A low-fi version of this might look something like

```js
function factors(number) {
  const factors = []
  for (let i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
    if (i % number === 0) {
      factors.push(i)
    }
  }
  return factors
}
```